# PowerShell error on sending e-mail

Tags: powershell, smtpclient

I have the following Powershell script that I would use to send an e-mail:

```
$smtpServer = "smtp.live.com"
$smtpPort = "465"
$credential = [Net.NetworkCredential](Get-Credential)

$smtpClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient $smtpServer, $smtpPort
$smtpClient.EnableSsl=$true
$smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials=$false
$smtpClient.Credentials= $credential

$smtpTo = "existing_email@hotmail.com"
$smtpFrom = "email@hotmail.com"
$messageSubject = "Testing Mail" 
$messageBody = "Hi, This is a Test"

$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpFrom, $smtpTo, $messageSubject, $messageBody

try
{
  $smtpClient.Send($message)
  Write-Output "Message sent."
}
catch
{
  $_.Exception.Message
  Write-Output "Message send failed."
}
```

But I receive this error:

```
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,mail.ps1

Exception calling "Send with "1" arguments" Failure Sending mail
```

What is wrong whit this code?

Comment: Add this to your catch block `$_.Exception.Message` to see what the actual problem is

Comment: And maybe you could also give us the full error message (to know what line causes the error).

Comment: Exception calling "Send with "1" arguments" Failure Sending mail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't defined `$smtpFrom` (address from which the e-mail is sent). Also, just a suggestion, why don't you use `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet, it's available from PowerShell 2.0

This code works for me without any issues with `smtp.live.com` and port `587` with `SSL`

```
$SmtpServer = 'smtp.live.com'
$SmtpUser = 'your_username@outlook.com'
$smtpPassword = 'your_password'
$MailTo = 'your_to_mail@example.com'
$MailFrom = 'your_username@outlook.com'
$MailSubject = "Test using $SmtpServer" 
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $SmtpUser, $($smtpPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force) 
Send-MailMessage -To "$MailTo" -from "$MailFrom" -Subject $MailSubject -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Credential $Credentials -UseSsl -Port 587
```

Comment: My mistake was the port. I don't know why the port I use in my email client give me the error. By the way, your solution can be considered accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I solved changing port to 25. But why I can't use IMAP ?